# How to receive the toolbox's messages

Tags: javascript, arcgis-10.2, geoprocessing-service, react

I developed a toolbox that reads an Excel file and fills up a feature layer. The toolbox works fine I just want to receive the messages at the client side to add a messaging log for the user to follow up with the tools work process.

I use SubmitJob to send the request, so I wrote a function that suppose to send back the status of the job, but I keep getting a status of "JobSubmitted" even when the tool already finished the job.

This is the function that executes the job by passing the URL of the published tool at the portal.

Is there something weird or incorrect in the way I constructed the function?

```
try {
     const jobInfo = await geoprocessor.submitJob(props.config.uploadExcelSubmitJobUrl, 
     params).then(async (jobInfo) => {
          const options = {
            interval: 5000,
            statusCallback: (j: JobInfo) => {
              setlogList(logList => [...logList, (<span>{`job status: ${jobInfo.jobStatus}`}</span>)]);
            }};
          await jobInfo.waitForJobCompletion(options).then(() => {
            jobInfo.fetchResultData('UploadExcelFile').then((result) => {
              console.log(result)
              jobInfo.destroy();
            }).catch(errorHandler);
          });
        });
      }
```

Comment: Is the service itself outputting messages? The service needs to have messages set to INFO. If it's only set to NONE, WARNING, ERROR, you'll only get the higher-level messages. This is a _Service_ level setting and has nothing to do with JavaScript/App. Run the tool in the Services Directory (REST) and confirm if you're getting messages or not.

Comment: This q/a has more details: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/311416/get-messages-from-geoprocessing-service?rq=1

Comment: I do have it on INFO. i can print arcpy mesages too.. it print everything

Comment: Looking at the code, and comparing to some old JS code, I don't see where you're actually getting _messages_ out of the result. Per https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/140323/parsing-geoprocessing-service-messages-using-arcgis-api-for-javascript/140337#140337 I suspect they'd be inside your _jobInfo_ - if you set a break point and inspect, are they there?

Comment: the messages array always null and  you're right i deleted the part when i try to access it but the job status suppose to change anyway..

Comment: I took the jobID tried to access the tool itself at the portal while working and the job is right and there are messages so how can it be that the messages array is empty and the jobstatus isn't changing?.. I think maybe the name of the tool is incorrect at the fetchResultData? I don't really know that i was supposed to pass there. that is the name of the tool at the description